# How do I return jsonp from web.api site in IIS 8.5?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I've created a web.api solution in Visual Studio 2013. Anticipating cross-domain issues I installed the WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp Nuget package. I created a web application in the solution that calls the web.api service from jquery. Typically my ajax requests looks like:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: uri + '/api/events/',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true
});
```

I had originally started the project in Windows 7 and recently was upgraded to Windows 10. This all works fine locally in VS 2013/IIS Express - the web.api returns a json array of events to the calling script. I also published the web.api project to a local web site running under IIS 10, all is good there as well.

So I deployed the web.api to a development server - Windows Server 2012 R2 running IIS 8.5. When I request http://devservername/api/events/ I get an error : ***A callback parameter was not provided in the request URI***

[Error Image - A callback parameter was not provided in the request URI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD3zL.png)

The development server runs asp.net 4.5. I'm concerned that I was able to not deal with the callback parameter locally but this technique fails on the target server. Or worse, it's a deployment/configuration issue. Can anyone recommend a best approach here?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the console to confirm that a callback parameter was included in the request URI?

Comment: I hadn't as the error occurred when trying to call the web.api method directly from Internet explorer. Appending ?callback=something to the request did provide some helpful feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little more digging and added some error logging and tracing to the web.api project. As it turns out the error displayed is correct - when trying to access the web.api methods from Internet Explorer unless the callback parameter is supplied this error will occur (as it should). Chrome and Firefox happily display an XML version of the datasource. In IE then if one appends ?callback=something then IE will attempt to return the data. jQuery hides all this by appending the callback parameter automatically in the AJAX request.

If one tries to call the web.api method from C# server-side then appending this parameter in the call is necessary:

```
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {

            //   wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/jsonp");
            NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
            nvc.Add("callback", "jsonCallback");
            wc.QueryString = nvc;

            try
            {
                string result = wc.DownloadString(MyWebApiUrl);
                var json = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(result, @".+\((.+)\).+").Groups[1].Value;
                events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event[]>(json);
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                events = new Event[] { };
            }
        }
```